# End a while loop that continue ask for string input until I enter -1

Tags: c++, arrays, string, codeblocks

I have to create a menu that holds item names, I can do it with a for loop that ends until the max has been reach, but how do I do it with a while loop that will continue ask until the max is reached or I enter -1

I tried with a for loop and it worked, but I have to use a while loop that can stop when I tell it to stop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void read_in_menu(char menu_list[][50], float price_list[], int& num_menu_items,
                  int MAX_MENU_ITEMS);

int main()
{
    const int MAX_MENU_ITEMS = 5;
    char menu_list[MAX_MENU_ITEMS][50];
    float price_list[MAX_MENU_ITEMS];
    int num_menu_items;

    read_in_menu(menu_list, price_list, num_menu_item, MAX_MENU_ITEMS);
}

void read_in_menu(char menu_list[][50], float price_list[], int& num_menu_items,
                  int MAX_MENU_ITEMS)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MENU_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Names: ";
        cin.getline(menu_list[i], 20);
    }
}
```

I want to use a while loop that will continue going until I input -1 or reach the maximum. I want to stop the while loop whenever I want instead of the for loop where I have to reach the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this should work:

```
int i = 0;
string input = "";
while(i < MAX_MENU_ITEMS || input == "-1") {
    cout << "Enter Names: ";
    cin.getline(input, 20);
    if(input != "-1") { //to avoid setting menu_list[i] = "-1"
        menu_list[i] = input;
    }
    MAX_MENU_ITEMS++;
}
```

or using break:

```
int i = 0;
string input = "";
while(i < MAX_MENU_ITEMS) {
    cout << "Enter Names: ";
    cin.getline(input, 20);
    if(input == "-1") { 
        break;
    }
    menu_list[i] = input;
    MAX_MENU_ITEMS++;
}
```

Comment: Hi thankyou! I was able to figure it out with a pointer, but I was storing -1 as one of the strings as well, yours solved that problem!

Comment: I recommend a quick bit of clean-up: `cin.getline(input, 20);` won't compile. [This particular form of `getline` will not accept a `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). `menu_list[i] = input;` also will not work. You can't assign a `std::string` to an `char` array. Either use `std::getline` and specify `std::string` throughout (vastly superior option), or suffer through everything being a `char` array (Superyuck).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to exit a loop you can use the `break` keyword.

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
    if(i > 10){
        break;
    }
    doWork();
}
```

Comment: You can also use `break` in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `for` loop to other loops. For example:

**For**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    DoSomething();
```

**While**

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 10){
    DoSomething();
    i++;
}
```

**do-while**

```
int i = 0;
do{
    DoSomething();
    i++;
}
while(i < 10);
```

To control the loops use `continue` and `break` keywords. Keyword `continue` will skip the current iteration of the loop and `break` will exit the loop. These are usually conditioned by `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it with a pointer lol.

```
void read_in_menu(char menu_list[5][20], float price_list[], int &num_menu_items, int MAX_MENU_ITEMS){
int i = 0;
char *p = "-1";
while(i<MAX_MENU_ITEMS){
cout << "Enter Name" << endl;
cin.getline(menu_list[i],20);
if(strcmp(menu_list[i], p)){
i++;
}else{
break;
}
}
}
```